# How to use bootstrap5 tooltip in react

Tags: reactjs, tooltip, bootstrap-5

I have react project with bootstrap packages

```
// npm install bootstrap@next
// npm install bootstrap-icons
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min';
import 'bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css'
```

Then I have the tooltip element

```
<i className="bi bi-align-center" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top"></i>
```

The [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/tooltips/#example-enable-tooltips-everywhere) says, we have to execute this javascript in order to enable bootstrap tooltip

```
var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
      var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
        return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl)
    })
```

So I put the code inside **componentDidMount** method, in a class where I am rendering the tooltip

but I am getting an error

> 'bootstrap' is not defined  no-undef

or when I adjust the import tag to

```
import { bootstrap } from 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min';
```

I get another error

```
Cannot read property 'Tooltip' of undefined
```

So I am confused how to enable this tooltip?

Comment: I think you just need `import { Tooltip } from 'bootstrap';` and then instead of `bootstrap.Tooltip` you use `Tooltip`

Comment: @gaitat It does not work :/ it is silly that you cannot use normal javascript or that you have to do some harakiri to make it work.

Comment: Working - https://therichpost.com/reactjs-bootstrap-5-tooltip-working-example/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to use react-bootstrap at all since **Bootstrap 5** is now vanilla JavaScript...

You can import Bootstrap 5 JS components like this (note .esm version for [modular importing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/javascript/#using-bootstrap-as-a-module))...

```
import { Tooltip } from 'bootstrap.esm.min.js'
```

then you can refer to the Tooltip like this...

```
    const tooltipTriggerList = document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]')
    const tooltipList = [...tooltipTriggerList].map(tooltipTriggerEl => new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl))
    return () => {
      tooltipList.map(t => t.dispose())
    }
```

[React Bootstrap Tooltip example](https://www.codeply.com/p/UdGIAbG2ZZ)

Comment: example links breaks for me when the component is removed. the tooltip stays and is not removed too. And this is enough as import `import { Tooltip } from 'bootstrap';` for bootstrap 5.2

Answer (score 9):

This is my vanilla TypeScript version.

1. Install and import bootstrap & typings

   ```
   npm i @types/bootstrap bootstrap
   ```

   ```
   import "bootstrap"
   import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
   ```
2. Create `Tooltip` component

   ```
   import { Tooltip as BsTooltip } from "bootstrap"
   import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react"

   export const Tooltip = (p: {children: JSX.Element, text: string}) => {
       const childRef = useRef(undefined as unknown as Element)

       useEffect(() => {
           const t = new BsTooltip(childRef.current, {
               title: p.text,
               placement: "right",
               trigger: "hover"
           })
           return () => t.dispose()
       }, [p.text])

       return React.cloneElement(p.children, { ref: childRef })
   }
   ```
3. Use

   ```
   <Tooltip text="Tooltip text">
       <button className="btn btn-primary" type="button">My button</button>
   </Tooltip>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

When using Bootstrap with React, it is highly recommended to use [React-Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/).

React-Bootstrap has an [`OverlayTrigger`](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/overlays/#overlay-trigger) component and a [`Tooltip`](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/overlays/#tooltips) component you can use for adding hover-able Tooltips.

In your case, it would look something like this

```js
<OverlayTrigger
  placement={'top'}
  delay={{ show: 250, hide: 400 }}
  overlay={
    <Tooltip>
      Tooltip on top
    </Tooltip>
  }
>
  <i className="bi bi-align-center" />
</OverlayTrigger>
```

Comment: Thank you, I will think about using react-bootstrap instead of bootstrap directly.

Comment: After adding `import { OverlayTrigger, Tooltip } from 'react-bootstrap';` the code works :-)

Answer (score 1):

### Here is a proper guide to use Tooltip in react

**Install Bootstrap via npm or yarn:**

Using npm:

```bash
npm install bootstrap
```

Using yarn:

```bash
yarn add bootstrap
```

**Import the necessary CSS and JavaScript files in your main application file** (e.g., `index.js`):

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js';
import './index.css'; // Your custom CSS if needed
import App from './App'; // Your main React component

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Now you can use Bootstrap's tooltip functionality in your React component:

```js
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const tooltipRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const tooltip = new window.bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipRef.current, {
      container: 'body',
      trigger: 'hover',
    });

    return () => {
      tooltip.dispose();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <button ref={tooltipRef} data-bs-toggle="tooltip" title="This is a tooltip message">
        Hover me for a tooltip
      </button>

      <span ref={tooltipRef} data-bs-toggle="tooltip" title="Another tooltip message">
        Hover me for another tooltip
      </span>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

In this example, we utilize the `useRef` hook to obtain references to the elements that require tooltips and leverage the `useEffect` hook to handle tooltip initialization and cleanup when the component mounts and unmounts.

Although we used `bootstrap` [v5+] in this demonstration, you can alternatively opt for a dedicated React Bootstrap library/package, such as `react-bootstrap`.

Answer (score 0):

For using bootstrap in React, it is recommended to use `react-bootstrap`.

The steps to integrate that in your project are:

1. Install bootstrap in your project by adding package through terminal : `npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap`
2. Add this in your `App.js`.
3. `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';`
4. Add tooltip in your component by importing tooltip as follows: `import { Tooltip} from 'react-bootstrap';`

**This would be the same for every `react-bootstrap` component**

*React-Bootstrap Tooltip documentation : https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/overlays/#tooltips*